# Does continuous variable confer greater power than categorical variable because of changing degrees of freedom?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, statistical-power, degrees-of-freedom

For the same dataset with continuous variable, we can force them into categorical variable (such as forcing discrete age variable into 1y-20y,20y-40y,40y-60y...) and do a Chi-squared test instead of Student's t-test. People say that this conversion will reduce statistical power due to the loss of information (age example above). Technically, can I understand the 'reduced power due to loss of information' as the decrease of degree of freedom from t-test to Chi-squared test, and therefore larger 'standardized deviation' is required to call statistical significance?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? When I think of losing information, I think of something like putting ages in groups like 30s and 40s, meaning that a 30-year-old and a 39-year-old are regarded as more similar (in fact, the same) than a 39-year-old and a 40-year-old.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean by 'loss of information'. I edited the context.

Comment: How do degrees of freedom come up?

Comment: I thought that converting continous variable (t-test) to categorical variable (Chi-squared test) resultes in decreased degree of freeedom, and therefore requires larger 'standardized deviation' to call statistical significance.

Comment: @unicorn Your thought is right: converting continuous variable to categories quickly consumes the degrees of freedom. Think of the extreme case, if each observation corresponds a separate category, then the model becomes non-estimable (too many parameters).

Comment: It's truly unclear what you mean by those phrases about SD and "calling statistical significance." However, the underlying principles are clear and you seem to be aware of them: treating the variable as categorical does use more DF, but in return the model is more flexible.  Any change in the significance of the variable will therefore depend on whether you gain enough from that flexibility.  You *won't* when the original fit is good; that is, nearly linear.  But generally you ought to consider using splines instead of discretizing your variable.